# Am I testing this correctly?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following method on a service class:

```
@Service
public class Service {
    (...)
    public Page<ChannelAccount> getByCustomerAndChannelType(Pageable pageable, Customer customer, ChannelType channelType) {
        return channelAccountRepository.findByCustomerAndChannelType(pageable, customer, channelType);
    }
}
```

This returns the expected result. Now I trying to build the unit test for it. So far I got this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChannelAccountServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ChannelAccountService channelAccountService;

    @Mock
    private ChannelAccountRepository channelAccountRepository;

    (...)
    @Test
    public void testGetByCustomerAndChannelTypePageable() {
        Page<ChannelAccount> pageResult = new PageImpl<>(channelAccountService.getAllChannelAccounts());
        Mockito.when(channelAccountRepository.findByCustomerAndChannelType(pageable, customer, ChannelType.FACEBOOK)).thenReturn(pageResult);
        Page<ChannelAccount> channelAccountPage = channelAccountRepository.findByCustomerAndChannelType(pageable, customer, ChannelType.FACEBOOK);
        assertEquals(pageResult, channelAccountPage);
    }
```

Somehow this doesn't feels right. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you post how you define channelAccountService and the channelAccountRepository. Also just to be 100% .. this should be a unit test not an integration test right?

Comment: No, the test doesn't test anything other than Mockito. It's supposed, according to its name, to test the service, but it never calls the service. It only calls the mocked repository, and tests that the repository returns what you told it to return.

Comment: Yes, unit test. The question is edited show how channelAccountService and channelAccountRepository are inserted to the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are calling this method as it has nothing to do with the case itself:

```
Page<ChannelAccount> pageResult = new PageImpl<>(channelAccountService.getAllChannelAccounts());
```

I would do the following in the test:

```
Pageable pageableStub = Mockito.mock(Pageable.class);
Page pageStub = Mockito.mock(Page.class);

Mockito.when(channelAccountRepository
    .findByCustomerAndChannelType(pageableStub, customer, ChannelType.FACEBOOK))
    .thenReturn(pageStub);

Page<ChannelAccount> channelAccountPage = channelAccountService
    .findByCustomerAndChannelType(pageableStub, customer, ChannelType.FACEBOOK);

assertTrue(pageResult == channelAccountPage);
```

I would check whether the objects are the same instances instead of equals (even more strict).